# Perl Script return value in DOS batch file

Tags: perl, error-handling, batch-file, exit-code

I have a DOS batch file that calls a Perl Script file:

```
ssutexec.pl prog=MyProg I_CARD=MyCard O_F071=ME007 F70P=MYF70P TRIG=MYTRIG
set status=%errorlevel%
if NOT %status% == 0 (
  echo *******************************************************
  echo   MPSBM070 JOB stopped with a RETURN CODE of %status%
  echo ************** END OF JOB *****************************
  goto JobEnd
 )
```

Inside the ssutexec.pl perl script file, an error condition is executed and the script exits with exit($status):

```
if ($status != 0)
 {
  system("ssutdttm.pl SSUTEXEC \"finished processing $prog_nam (Abnormal End) on\"") ;
  print "******************************************************************" ;
  print "              JOB STOPPED - Due to Return code of ($status)" ;
  print "*****************END OF JOB***************************************" ;
  system("ssutdttm.pl SSUTEXEC \"finished processing $prog_nam (Abnormal End) on\"") ;
  system("ssuttmdr.pl -c -b $starttime -m \"$prog_nam\"") ;
  exit($status) ;
 }
```

I am not a perl script guy.  Errorlevel isn't being triggered so I am not getting the error.  How can I trap the value of the perl script exit code within my DOS batch file?

INDLUDING EDITS:
The new batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 


if not defined run_env goto ScriptExit

echo ******************************************************************
echo *                      MYPROG                                  *
echo ******************************************************************

perl ssutdttm.pl MYPROG Start -
perl ssutexec.pl prog=MyProg I_CARD=MyCard O_F071=ME007 F70P=MYF70P TRIG=MYTRIG
set status=!errorlevel!
if NOT %status% == 0 (
  echo *******************************************************
  echo   MYPROG JOB stopped with a RETURN CODE of %status%
  echo ************** END OF JOB *****************************
  goto JobEnd
 )

:JobEnd
  if %status% == 0 (
    echo *******************************************************
    echo       NORMAL END OF JOB - RETURN CODE of %status%
    echo ******** NORMAL END OF JOB ****************************
   ) ELSE (
    echo !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    echo     ABNORMAL END OF JOB - RETURN CODE of %status%
    echo !!!!!! ABNORMAL END OF JOB !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
   )
  ssutdttm.pl MYPROG end - 
  exit /b %status%
::
:ScriptExit
echo run_env: %run_env%
```

Comment: Are you sure `$status` is being set to a non-zero value in the Perl script?

Comment: @Jonah...yes, the Print statement in the code prints out a value of 44

Comment: @MikeTWebb What is the value of $status after those last two system() calls right before the exit?

Answer (score 2):

Working with batch files can really be a pain (DOS batch files make bash scripts look wonderful, and bash stinks!). The problem could be cropping up from the way batch files handle variable expansion. Here's something to try:

1. Add the following line to the top of your batch script (I usually put it at the top, just under my `@echo off` line): `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`
2. Change all `%ERRORLEVEL%` references to `!ERRORLEVEL!` instead (exclamation marks instead of percent signs).

These changes will have the effect of causing variables to get expanded at execution time, rather than at parse-time. I've seen the `%ERRORLEVEL%` value get mangled when not using the delayed expansion option. Read this [EnableDelayedExpansion information page](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for more.

Comment: @Jonah...I will aslo give you approach a try tomorrow and post the result.  Thanks as well!

Comment: @Jonah...I tried this and still my scenario doesn't see the !errorlevel! variable

Comment: Hmm. Here's another thing to try ... try wrapping your conditional in quotes: `if not "%status%" == "0"`

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be calling `perl.exe` with the script as an argument:

`perl ssutexec.pl prog=MyProg ...`

In my tests, if I have just the script name, I get prompted for what I want to use to open the `test.pl` file.  That means `perl.exe` is not executing my Perl code.

Your file associations could likely be there, but your script could still be failing because of the [nuances of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410375/329921).

I tested with my two very simple scripts:

test.bat

```
@ECHO OFF

perl test.pl

set status=%errorlevel%

if NOT %status% == 0 (
 echo status was set with value of %status%
)
```

and test.pl

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $status = 44;

exit($status)
```

and the expected output:

```
C:\Dropbox\Programming\Perl\Learn\blah>test
status was set with value of 44
```

Comment: The [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) pragma enables a bunch of safety checks on your code. Using it in production environments is encouraged. Don't be surprised if your script initially chokes, though; it's not called "strict" for nothing.

Comment: @Craig....I tried the above scenario and it worked with test.pl being called by perl and without. Andy ideas?