# How can I pass command line parameters to a Perl script?

Tags: perl

I am using Active Perl and the `@ARGV` does not seem to work.  The script won't pick up my arguments. Example:

```
auto_setdate.exe 12 5 2020
```

Is there another variable besides `@ARGV` I need to use?  Or try something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7410375/2139766

Comment: @AnFi None of those affect a `.exe`, but they could be useful if the .exe is doing something like `system("foo.pl ...")`